# Matlab Namespaces

Tags: matlab, namespaces

I have the following problem: I have Namespaces in my folder structure e.g.

```
+Something

---Test1.m

---Test1.params
```

.params is just a file which contains JSON.

in Test1.m there is a function which loads the json via fileread. If there is no Namespace structure and everything is in root it's working fine. But Now I should be able to do:

```
fileread('Something.Test1.params');
```

but it cant find it.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Why wouldn't you call the file something like `params.json` rather than `Test1.params`? I suspect you're confusing MATLAB because it's looking within the class `Test1` for the function `params`, rather than for a file of type `.params`.

Comment: Nope, renaming it to `.json` is not working. What I did now is I added another file called `Test11.json` but it still says `Could not open file Something.Test11.json. No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using path to the file. Something.Test1 is indeed full name of the function/script, but full filename is "+Something\Test1.params".

Comment: Great, working fine! just sticked to the Namespace scheme too much... pretty dumb from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on MATLAB to find the file for you in its path. This is a bad idea, someone else could create a file with the same name and put it earlier in the MATLAB path (e.g. in their working MATLAB directory) and break your code.

The function [`mfilename`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html) returns the full path of the currently executing M-file. Use that path to find your data file:

```
p = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
p = fullfile(p,'Test1.params');
data = fileread(p);
```